# regex just only match first substring

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this

> BALANCE:"5048543747",BALDEFOVD:"5119341413",ACCTNO:"0001000918",

I've using REGEX

> (.*?),

Result i've received just the first substring is

> BALANCE:"5048543747"

in fact, the result which i want get is the array include

> {
>
> BALANCE:"5048543747"
>
> BALDEFOVD:"5119341413"
>
> ACCTNO:"0001000918"
>
> }

Can anyone help me. Many thanks.

**EDIT**

Code i've using

> Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?),");
>
> Matcher matcher =pattern.matcher("BALANCE:\"5048543747\",BALDEFOVD:\"5119341413\",ACCTNO:\"0001000918\",");
>
> if (matcher.find())
>
> {
>
> System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group(1));
>
> }

**Result i'v received**

> BALANCE:"5048543747"

Comment: Could you add the code you are using?

Comment: Works fine for me. Please post your code.

Comment: Why not just `split(",")` ?

Comment: Hix. I'm so idiot. So ez to fix it. Thanks AJ :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
String input = "BALANCE:\"5048543747\",BALDEFOVD:\"5119341413\",ACCTNO:\"0001000918\",";
String pattern = "(.*?),";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group(1));
}
```

After seeing one the comments, it might be easier for you to just split the string on comma.

Comment: Yep. Thanks Tim Biegeleisen. i fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while(matcher.find){
    System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

The [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) in Java can be a bit confusing at first, especially when matching on groups. In the above example, `matcher.group(0)` is always the entire regular expression. `matcher.group(1)` is matches to the **first group** you specify in your regex. `matcher.group(2)` would return matches to the **second group** in your regex, if you happened to have one (your example does not). Call `matcher.find` to retrieve the next set of matches.

Answer (score 0):

This will be usefull

```
(\w+:"\d+")
```

\w+ takes the full word until literal :
then process the literal "
\d+ takes the numbers until the next literal "
and you take all the information to match